# Run script skipping files

Tags: linux, bash

I have a quite simple script I'd like to write just using bash.

Given a folder with 0..N *.XML files; I want to sort those by name and remove N-10 files (**leave the last 10 in place**).

I've been tinkering with find and tail/head but couldn't figure a way

```
find /mnt/user/Temporary/1 -name *.xml | tail -n +10 | rm
```

Please read up. **It is about keeping the last 10. If there are 10 or less files, none should be deleted!**

**EDIT:**
As someone closed, but did not repoen the question, here is the solution for those getting here with the same question.

```
#!/bin/bash
files=()
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    files+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find . -name *.xml -print0 | sort)
Limit=$((${#files[@]}-10))
count=0
while [  $Limit -gt $count ]; do
    rm "${files[count]}"
    let count=count+1 
done
```

*Maybe some linux "pro" can optimize it or give it some parameters (like limit, path and file pattern) to make it callable anywhere.*

Comment: Give [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) a go, it autodetects common issues including [piping to rm](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2216) and [not quoting 'find' globs](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2061)

Comment: Put the list of all files in an array, delete first N-10 if N>10.

Comment: Not a duplicate. Please read again. I'm not struggling with rm, It's about keep 10 (or less) files.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: New answer

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=$(find *.xml | wc -l)

[ "$files" -lt 10 ] && echo "Files are less than 10..." && exit 1

count=$(($files-10))

for i in $(find *.xml | sort -V); do
    [ $count -eq 0 ] && echo "Done" && exit 1
    rm $i
    ((count--))
done
```

- $files stores the number of *.xml in the folder
- if the number is less or equal to 10 exit
- set a counter that of the number of files to delete
- loop through each file in order
- if the counter is equal to 0 exit
- if not remove the file and increment the counter

Comment: I see, thank you for the rectification, someone replied in the comment above with the right solution.

Comment: This actually will just print/remove the last 10 lines.

Comment: I want to keep the last 10... and also what happens if there are less than 11 files in the folder?

Comment: If you want to delete them in case are less than 10 should write a function that:
finds all the .xml, sort them, check if there are at least 10 files, if more than 10 remove them, if less ... do nothing?

Comment: Does generate some errors... probably connected to the bash version. See my solution on top.

Comment: Bash 5.0.7, macOS environment.